# RecycleViewer not showing anything in the list after update in Firebase database

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I got a problem and I can't see an error in my code, maybe You'll help me. I've got an application in Android Studio that uses connection with Firebase. I add products to the database by a button and in the activity that holds RecycleViever, it lists that product there. The problem is that RecycleViewer shows nothing, even though that my button adds product to the Firebase. That RecycleViewer should list products from Firebase. I add product with It's structure:

```
data class Product(var name: String, var price: Double, var quantity: Long, var bought: Boolean) {
    var id: String = ""
    companion object {
        fun fromContentValues(values: ContentValues?): Product {
            values?.let{
                return Product(
                    values.getAsString("name"),
                    values.getAsDouble("price"),
                    values.getAsLong("amount"),
                    values.getAsBoolean("bought"))
            } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

    @Exclude
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "id" to id,
            "name" to name,
            "price" to price,
            "quantity" to quantity,
            "bought" to bought
        )
    }
}
```

Product Repository:

```
class ProductRepository(private val dbRef: DatabaseReference) {

    fun insert(product: Product) {
        val key = dbRef.push().key
        if (key == null) {
            Log.w("error", "Couldn't get push key for posts")
            return
        }

        product.id = key
        val productValues = product.toMap()

        val childUpdates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
                key to productValues
        )

        dbRef.updateChildren(childUpdates)
    }

    fun update(product: Product){
        val productValues = product.toMap()

        val childUpdates = hashMapOf<String, Any>(
                product.id to productValues
        )

        dbRef.updateChildren(childUpdates)
    }

    fun delete(key: String){
        dbRef.child(key).removeValue()
    }
}
```

Product ViewModel:

```
class ProductViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val repo: ProductRepository
    val allProducts: MutableList<Product>

    init {
        allProducts = arrayListOf()
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val reference : DatabaseReference = database.getReference("database/products")

        var name: String
        var price: Double
        var amount: Long
        var bought: Boolean
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (product in snapshot.children) {
                    name = product.child("name").value as String
                    price = product.child("price").value as Double
                    amount = product.child("amount").value as Long
                    bought = product.child("bought").value as Boolean
                    val newProduct = Product(name, price, amount, bought)
                        allProducts.add(newProduct)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("error", "loadPost:onCancelled", error.toException())
            }
        })

        repo = ProductRepository(reference)
    }

    fun insert(product: Product) {
            repo.insert(product)
    }

    fun update(product: Product) {
            repo.update(product)
    }

    fun delete(product: Product) {
            repo.delete(product.id)
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
class ProductsAdapter(val productViewModel: ProductViewModel) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var products = mutableListOf<Product>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = ListElementBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentProduct = products[position]
        holder.binding.rvTv1.text = currentProduct.name
        holder.binding.rvTv2.text = currentProduct.price.toString()
        holder.binding.rvTv3.text = currentProduct.amount.toString()
        holder.binding.rvCb1.isChecked = currentProduct.bought
        holder.binding.bted.setOnClickListener {
            currentProduct.name = holder.binding.rvTv1.text.toString()
            currentProduct.price = holder.binding.rvTv2.text.toString().toDouble()
            currentProduct.amount = holder.binding.rvTv3.text.toString().toLong()
            currentProduct.bought = holder.binding.rvCb1.isChecked
            productViewModel.update(currentProduct)
        }
        holder.binding.btdel.setOnClickListener {
            productViewModel.delete(currentProduct)
            products.remove(currentProduct)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = products.size

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ListElementBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    fun setProducts() {
        this.products = productViewModel.allProducts
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addProduct(product: Product) {
        productViewModel.insert(product)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

And finally activity that Lists it all:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.rv1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext)
        binding.rv1.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(baseContext, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        val productViewModel = ProductViewModel(this.application)
        binding.rv1.adapter = ProductsAdapter(productViewModel)
        (binding.rv1.adapter as ProductsAdapter).setProducts()
        binding.bt5.setOnClickListener() {
            val name = et1.text.toString()
            val price = et3.text.toString().toDouble()
            val amount = et2.text.toString().toLong()
            val bought = false
            val product = Product(name, price, amount, bought)
            (binding.rv1.adapter as ProductsAdapter).addProduct(product)
            et1.text.clear()
            et2.text.clear()
            et3.text.clear()
            }
            binding.rv1.adapter = ProductsAdapter(productViewModel)
    }
}
```

I literally have no idea, why it's not showing anything. Maybe You can help me.

Comment: I think you need check your permission internet access on manifest, check your data return from database, check your data return from viewModel

Comment: When i debug it, i can see that there might be something wrong with binding. It never comes to "onBindViewHolder" but I don't know why.

Comment: is debugger going inside the adapter class or not??

Comment: @Sathyan Actually no, but I don't know why

Comment: @voteforkodaline how about the size of data before add to adapter?

Comment: I guess there two potential bugs. A) you are setting the adapter 2 times. Second-time data may be empty. B) Data may not be updated when you add the item to list referenced by viewmodel in adapter class.  try adding break point and see the value of ```override fun getItemCount(): Int = products.size```

Comment: I haven't used Firebase, but I assume you're pulling the products asynchoronously, and ``onDataChange`` is where you get the results and ``allProducts`` is updated? If so that async callback probably happens after your adapter has finished setting up, and after your call to ``setProducts``. You'll need some way to push a notification to the adapter whenever ``allProducts`` updates, so it can display the new data

Comment: Yea, i think i need a notifier just like notifyDataSetChanged(). Any ideas what i can put there to notify my Adapter? Never used that onDataChanged() function.

Comment: Please help me guys :(